# Temperature heat map : wrong weekday/year

Tags: python-3.x, csv, time-series, heatmap, temperature

I'd like to have a simple heat map of yearly data from this csv file https://easymagic-secret.fr/codes/test5-ko2.csv.

When I launch this code, my heat map returns wrong results

```
from pandas import Series
from pandas import DataFrame
from pandas import TimeGrouper
from matplotlib import pyplot
series = Series.from_csv('https://easymagic-secret.fr/codes/test5-ko2.csv',sep=';', header=0)
groups = series.groupby(TimeGrouper('A'))
years = DataFrame()
for name, group in groups:
    years[name.year] = group.values
years = years.T
pyplot.matshow(years, fignum = True, aspect='auto',cmap=pyplot.cm.coolwarm)
pyplot.show()
years
```

[image]

Results series return good results

```
from pandas import Series
from pandas import DataFrame
from pandas import TimeGrouper
from matplotlib import pyplot
#series = Series.from_csv('dataset/daily-minimum-temperatures.csv', header=0)
series = Series.from_csv('https://easymagic-secret.fr/codes/test5-ko2.csv',sep=';', header=0)
series

Out : 
Date
2009-01-01     2.6
2009-02-01     0.1
2009-03-01     0.4
2009-04-01    -0.6
2009-05-01     0.3
2009-06-01    -4.2
2009-07-01    -3.4
```

Do you have a solution to fix it ?

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. I expected real temperature in the heat map. for instance in January 2009 temperature should be cooler (ie : the 6 first days in 2009 in my csv file are 2.6, 0.1, 0.4, -0.6, 0.3, -4.2) and the dataframe years give me (2.6  , 0.1 ,  10.8  , 9.9  , 15.1, 19.2). That why, when I observe heat map, i see red color and it should not. We unfortunately never had 19.2 °C in January in France :-) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I just find the solution... my csv file had french data format 01/01/2009 instead of 2009-01-01...